Generalization of why the area of a surface of revolution is not $2 \pi \int_{a}^{b} (y) dx$
Based on the posts Areas versus volumes of revolution: why does the area require approximation by a cone? and Why is surface area not simply..., approximating an ND quantity in an ND region using N-1D pieces is "easy" and errors almost correct themselves, but approximating an ND quantity in an N+1D region using N-1D pieces is "hard" and prone to errors. Is there a formalization of this idea in the real analysis or differential geometry fields, or perhaps elsewhere?

Using cylinders instead of cones is, at least in retrospect, questionable because "the error is proportional to thickness, so the total error doesn't vanish in the limit." Geometric measure theory may be a natural starting point in general.
